# Razor Pages PDF generation with Rotativa - @Model null

Tags: asp.net-core, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, razor-pages

I have a web app build with .net core 3.1 Razor Pages. I need to add functionality to generate a PDF from a view. Generally the library is working because i can generate a static PDF, but the problem occurs when I want to use model to seed the template.

The `PageModel` looks like this:

```
    public class DetailsPdfModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ICablesData cablesData;
        private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

        public DetailsPdfModel(ICablesData cablesData, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.cablesData = cablesData;
            this.configuration = configuration;
        }

        public Cable Cable { get; set; }

        public IActionResult OnGet(int cableId)
        {
            Cable = cablesData.GetById(cableId);

            if (Cable == null)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("NotFound");
            }
            else
            {
                return new ViewAsPdf("DetailsPdf", this);
            }
        }
    }
```

The view looks like this:

```
@page
@model DetailsPdfModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>DetailsPdf</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>@Model.Cable.Name</p>
</body>
</html>
```

When I am trying to get the pdf the exception occurs. I noticed that the `@Model` is always `null`. If I change the `return new ViewAsPdf("DetailsPdf", this);` to `return Page();` the `@Model` is not `null` but after that is only regular view not the pdf file.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I change the return new ViewAsPdf("DetailsPdf", this); to return Page(); the @Model is not null but after that is only regular view not the pdf file.

That's because `ViewAsPdf` is not designed for Razor Page. And `Rotativa` doesn't expose a built-in API for RazorPage. For more details, see source code of [Rotativa.AspNetCore](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa.AspNetCore/tree/master/Rotativa.AspNetCore).

As a walkaround, you could create a custom `RazorPageAsPdf` class to achieve the same goal as below:

```
public class DetailsPdfModel : PageModel
{
    ...

    public IActionResult OnGet(int cableId)
    public RazorPageAsPdf OnGet(int cableId)
    {
        Cable = cablesData.GetById(cableId);

        if (Cable == null)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("NotFound");
        }
        else
        {
            return new ViewAsPdf("DetailsPdf", this);
            return new RazorPageAsPdf(this);       // we don't need page path because it can be determined by current route
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my implementation of RazorPageAsPdf for your reference:

```cs
public class RazorPageAsPdf : AsPdfResultBase
{
    private readonly IRazorViewEngine _razorViewEngine;
    private readonly ITempDataProvider _tempDataProvider;
    private readonly IRazorPageActivator _activator;    
    private string _razorPageName {get;set;}
    public PageModel PageModel {get;set;}
    public RazorPageAsPdf(PageModel pageModel)
    {
        PageModel = pageModel;
        var httpContext = pageModel.HttpContext;
        this._razorPageName = httpContext.Request.RouteValues["page"].ToString().Trim('/');
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(_razorPageName)){
            throw new ArgumentException("there's no such a 'page' in this context");
        }
        this._razorViewEngine =  httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IRazorViewEngine>();
        this._tempDataProvider=  httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITempDataProvider>();
        this._activator = httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IRazorPageActivator>();
    }

    private ViewContext GetViewContext( ActionContext actionContext, IRazorPage page, StringWriter sw)
    {
        var view = new RazorView( _razorViewEngine, _activator, new List<IRazorPage>(), page, HtmlEncoder.Default, new DiagnosticListener(nameof(RazorPageAsPdf)));
        return new ViewContext( actionContext, view, this.PageModel.ViewData, this.PageModel.TempData, sw, new HtmlHelperOptions());
    } 

    private async Task<string> RenderPageAsString(ActionContext actionContext){
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var pageResult = this._razorViewEngine.FindPage(actionContext, this._razorPageName);;
            if (pageResult.Page == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException($"The page {this._razorPageName} cannot be found.");
            }
            var viewContext = this.GetViewContext(actionContext, pageResult.Page, sw);
            var page = (Page)pageResult.Page;
            page.PageContext = this.PageModel.PageContext;
            page.ViewContext = viewContext;
            _activator.Activate(page, viewContext);
            await page.ExecuteAsync();
            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }

    protected override async Task<byte[]> CallTheDriver(ActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var html = await this.RenderPageAsString(actionContext);
        // copied from https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa.AspNetCore/blob/c907afa8c7dd6a565d307901741c336c429fc698/Rotativa.AspNetCore/ViewAsPdf.cs#L147-L151
        string baseUrl = string.Format("{0}://{1}",  actionContext.HttpContext.Request.Scheme, actionContext.HttpContext.Request.Host);
        var htmlForWkhtml = Regex.Replace(html.ToString(), "<head>", string.Format("<head><base href=\"{0}\" />", baseUrl), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        byte[] fileContent = WkhtmltopdfDriver.ConvertHtml(this.WkhtmlPath, this.GetConvertOptions(), htmlForWkhtml);
        return fileContent;
    }
    protected override string GetUrl(ActionContext context) => string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Great solution, thanks. I have only changed the return type of the OnGet method to ```IActionResult ``` because without it we can't use the ```RedirectToPage()``` method. But generally everything works great.

Comment: Spot on! Just a simple edit, I had to replace `this._razorPageName = httpContext.Request.RouteValues["page"].ToString().Trim('/');` to `this._razorPageName = pageModel.RouteData.Values["page"].ToString().Trim('/');`