# Problem Generating a PDF from html using Rotativa

Tags: c#, microsoft-edge, .net-5, rotativa

I have an MVC page that use a combination of Razor and C# code to render the html output. The page renders fine in the browser. However, in my browser when I use Rotativa to generate a PDF to print the page I get what seems to be JSON output instead of the formatted PDF.

I am using Visual Studio 2019 with .NET 5.0 and Rotativa 1.7.3.

I know I could try other HTML-to-PDF but Rotativa seems to be the best open source alternative.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong so I can get the output to render as a PDF?

I am including excerpts of my code rendering the page, the Rotativa code and the "PDF" output.

```C#
 public async Task<IActionResult> PayrollView(int SelectedCompanyID, string endingWeekString, string endingDateString, int? SelectedEmployeeID)
        {
            linq query...

            PayrollReportView payrollReportView = new PayrollReportView
            {
                PayrollDetails = await payrollReport.ToListAsync()
            };

            return View(payrollReportView);
        }

public ViewAsPdf PrintPayroll(int SelectedCompanyID, string endingWeekString, string endingDateString, int? SelectedEmployeeID)
        {

            linq query...

            PayrollReportView payrollReportView = new PayrollReportView
            {
                PayrollDetails = payrollReport.ToList()
            };

            var report = new ViewAsPdf("PayrollView",payrollReportView);
            return report;
        }
```

The link in the browser (I tried both Brave and Edge and confirmed that Edge opens PDFs) is:

https://localhost:44383/PayrollReports/PrintPayroll?SelectedCompanyID=13&endingWeekString=2021-11-26

The JSON like excerpt follows: the ... represent additional data which I excluded for brevity.

```
{
  "viewName": "PayrollView",
  "masterName": "",
  "model": {
    "payrollDetails": [
      {
        "earningsID": 290,
        "companyID": 13,
        "companyName": "\"D..,\"employees\":null},..\"endingDate\":null},",
        "pageSize": null,
        "pageWidth": null,
        "pageHeight": null,
        "pageOrientation": null,
        "pageMargins": {},
        "wkhtmltopdfPath": "",
        "isLowQuality": false,
        "copies": null,
        "isGrayScale": false,
        "fileName": null,
        "wkhtmlPath": "",
        "cookieName": ".ASPXAUTH",
        "formsAuthenticationCookieName": ".ASPXAUTH",
        "customHeaders": null,
        "cookies": null,
        "post": null,
        "isJavaScriptDisabled": false,
        "minimumFontSize": null,
        "proxy": null,
        "userName": null,
        "password": null,
        "customSwitches": null,
        "saveOnServerPath": null,
        "contentDisposition": 0
      }
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

**UPDATES:**

My problems are with both Edge and Brave. My view and Pdf Controller events are shown below. I have no Javascript or AJAX because right now I am doing everything server side.

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> PayrollView(int SelectedCompanyID, string endingWeekString, string endingDateString, int? SelectedEmployeeID)
        {
            DateTime dateEndingWeek;

            // Convert endingWeek to a date variable
            if (endingWeekString == null || endingWeekString.Length == 0)
            {
                dateEndingWeek = System.DateTime.Today;
            }
            else
            {
                dateEndingWeek = DateTime.Parse(endingWeekString);
            };

            DateTime dateEndingDate;
            // Convert endingDateString to a date variable
            if (endingDateString == null || endingDateString.Length == 0)
            {
                dateEndingDate = System.DateTime.Today;
            }
            else
            {
                dateEndingDate = DateTime.Parse(endingDateString);
            };

            // Base query
            var payrollReport = from company in _context.Company
                                join employee in _context.Employees
                                on company.CompanyID equals employee.CompanyID
                                join payroll in _context.EmployeeEarnings
                                on employee.EmployeeID equals payroll.EmployeeID
                                orderby company.CompanyID, payroll.EmployeeID, payroll.WeekEndingDate
                                select new PayrollReport
                                {
                                    EarningsID = payroll.EarningsID,
                                    CompanyID = company.CompanyID,
                                    CompanyName = company.CompanyName,
                                    EmployeeID = employee.EmployeeID,
                                    EmployeeName = employee.EmployeeName,
                                    EmployeeTypeID = employee.EmployeeTypeID,
                                    SSN = employee.SSN.Substring(5, 4),
                                    WeekEndingDate = payroll.WeekEndingDate,
                                    GrossEarnings = payroll.GrossEarnings,
                                    Period401K = payroll.Period401K,
                                    Period401KCatchUp = payroll.Period401KCatchUp,
                                    FederalWithholding = payroll.FederalWithholding,
                                    SSNWithholding = payroll.SSNWithholding,
                                    MedicareWithholding = payroll.MedicareWithholding,
                                    StateWithholding = payroll.StateWithholding,
                                    NetPay = payroll.NetPay,
                                    Tips = payroll.Tips == null ? 0 : payroll.Tips,
                                    Tips_Cash = payroll.Tips_Cash == null ? 0 : payroll.Tips_Cash,
                                    FedExtraWithholding = payroll.FedExtraWithholding,
                                    StateExtraWithholding = payroll.StateExtraWithholding
                                };

            // Check Filters
            if (SelectedCompanyID != 0)
                payrollReport = payrollReport.Where(x => x.CompanyID == SelectedCompanyID);
            if (endingWeekString != null && endingDateString != null)
                payrollReport = payrollReport.Where(x => x.WeekEndingDate >= dateEndingWeek && x.WeekEndingDate <= dateEndingDate);
            else if (endingWeekString != null)
                payrollReport = payrollReport.Where(x => x.WeekEndingDate == dateEndingWeek);
            if (SelectedEmployeeID.HasValue)
                payrollReport = payrollReport.Where(x => x.EmployeeID == SelectedEmployeeID);

            PayrollReportView payrollReportView = new PayrollReportView
            {
                PayrollDetails = await payrollReport.ToListAsync()
            };

            if (endingDateString != null)
                payrollReportView.endingDate = endingDateString;

            // Calculate Sum record if an employee and "end" date are specified

            decimal grossTotal = 0;
            decimal gross401KTotal = 0;
            decimal gross401KCatchUpTotal = 0;
            decimal federalTotal = 0;
            decimal SSNTotal = 0;
            decimal medicareTotal = 0;
            decimal stateTotal = 0;
            decimal netTotal = 0;
            decimal tipsTotal = 0;
            decimal tipsCashTotal = 0;
            decimal extraFederalTotal = 0;
            decimal extraStateTotal = 0;
            foreach (var payroll in payrollReportView.PayrollDetails)
            {
                grossTotal += payroll.GrossEarnings;
                gross401KTotal += payroll.Period401K;
                gross401KCatchUpTotal += payroll.Period401KCatchUp;
                federalTotal += payroll.FederalWithholding;
                SSNTotal += payroll.SSNWithholding;
                medicareTotal += payroll.MedicareWithholding;
                stateTotal += payroll.StateWithholding;
                netTotal += payroll.NetPay;
                tipsTotal = (decimal)(tipsTotal + payroll.Tips);
                tipsCashTotal = (decimal)(tipsCashTotal + payroll.Tips_Cash);
                extraFederalTotal = (decimal)(extraFederalTotal + payroll.FedExtraWithholding);
                extraStateTotal = (decimal)(extraStateTotal + payroll.StateExtraWithholding);
            }
            payrollReportView.SumGrossEarnings = grossTotal;
            payrollReportView.SumPeriod401K = gross401KTotal;
            payrollReportView.SumPeriod401KCatchUp = gross401KCatchUpTotal;
            payrollReportView.SumFederalWithholding = federalTotal;
            payrollReportView.SumSSNWithholding = SSNTotal;
            payrollReportView.SumMedicareWithholding = medicareTotal;
            payrollReportView.SumStateWithholding = stateTotal;
            payrollReportView.SumNetPay = netTotal;
            payrollReportView.SumTips = tipsTotal;
            payrollReportView.SumTips_Cash = tipsCashTotal;
            payrollReportView.SumFederalWithholding = extraFederalTotal;
            payrollReportView.SumStateExtraWithholding = extraStateTotal;
            return View(payrollReportView);
        }

        public ViewAsPdf PrintPayroll(int SelectedCompanyID, string endingWeekString, string endingDateString, int? SelectedEmployeeID)
        {
            DateTime dateEndingWeek;

            // Convert endingWeek to a date variable
            if (endingWeekString == null || endingWeekString.Length == 0)
            {
                dateEndingWeek = System.DateTime.Today;
            }
            else
            {
                dateEndingWeek = DateTime.Parse(endingWeekString);
            };

            DateTime dateEndingDate;
            // Convert endingDateString to a date variable
            if (endingDateString == null || endingDateString.Length == 0)
            {
                dateEndingDate = System.DateTime.Today;
            }
            else
            {
                dateEndingDate = DateTime.Parse(endingDateString);
            };

            // Base query
            var payrollReport = from company in _context.Company
                                join employee in _context.Employees
                                on company.CompanyID equals employee.CompanyID
                                join payroll in _context.EmployeeEarnings
                                on employee.EmployeeID equals payroll.EmployeeID
                                orderby company.CompanyID, payroll.EmployeeID, payroll.WeekEndingDate
                                select new PayrollReport
                                {
                                    EarningsID = payroll.EarningsID,
                                    CompanyID = company.CompanyID,
                                    CompanyName = company.CompanyName,
                                    EmployeeID = employee.EmployeeID,
                                    EmployeeName = employee.EmployeeName,
                                    EmployeeTypeID = employee.EmployeeTypeID,
                                    SSN = employee.SSN.Substring(5, 4),
                                    WeekEndingDate = payroll.WeekEndingDate,
                                    GrossEarnings = payroll.GrossEarnings,
                                    Period401K = payroll.Period401K,
                                    Period401KCatchUp = payroll.Period401KCatchUp,
                                    FederalWithholding = payroll.FederalWithholding,
                                    SSNWithholding = payroll.SSNWithholding,
                                    MedicareWithholding = payroll.MedicareWithholding,
                                    StateWithholding = payroll.StateWithholding,
                                    NetPay = payroll.NetPay,
                                    Tips = payroll.Tips == null ? 0 : payroll.Tips,
                                    Tips_Cash = payroll.Tips_Cash == null ? 0 : payroll.Tips_Cash,
                                    FedExtraWithholding = payroll.FedExtraWithholding,
                                    StateExtraWithholding = payroll.StateExtraWithholding
                                };

            // Check Filters
            if (SelectedCompanyID != 0)
                payrollReport = payrollReport.Where(x => x.CompanyID == SelectedCompanyID);
            if (endingWeekString != null && endingDateString != null)
                payrollReport = payrollReport.Where(x => x.WeekEndingDate >= dateEndingWeek && x.WeekEndingDate <= dateEndingDate);
            else if (endingWeekString != null)
                payrollReport = payrollReport.Where(x => x.WeekEndingDate == dateEndingWeek);
            if (SelectedEmployeeID.HasValue)
                payrollReport = payrollReport.Where(x => x.EmployeeID == SelectedEmployeeID);

            PayrollReportView payrollReportView = new PayrollReportView
            {
                PayrollDetails = payrollReport.ToList()
            };

            if (endingDateString != null)
                payrollReportView.endingDate = endingDateString;

            // Calculate Sum record if an employee and "end" date are specified

            decimal grossTotal = 0;
            decimal gross401KTotal = 0;
            decimal gross401KCatchUpTotal = 0;
            decimal federalTotal = 0;
            decimal SSNTotal = 0;
            decimal medicareTotal = 0;
            decimal stateTotal = 0;
            decimal netTotal = 0;
            decimal tipsTotal = 0;
            decimal tipsCashTotal = 0;
            decimal extraFederalTotal = 0;
            decimal extraStateTotal = 0;
            foreach (var payroll in payrollReportView.PayrollDetails)
            {
                grossTotal += payroll.GrossEarnings;
                gross401KTotal += payroll.Period401K;
                gross401KCatchUpTotal += payroll.Period401KCatchUp;
                federalTotal += payroll.FederalWithholding;
                SSNTotal += payroll.SSNWithholding;
                medicareTotal += payroll.MedicareWithholding;
                stateTotal += payroll.StateWithholding;
                netTotal += payroll.NetPay;
                tipsTotal = (decimal)(tipsTotal + payroll.Tips);
                tipsCashTotal = (decimal)(tipsCashTotal + payroll.Tips_Cash);
                extraFederalTotal = (decimal)(extraFederalTotal + payroll.FedExtraWithholding);
                extraStateTotal = (decimal)(extraStateTotal + payroll.StateExtraWithholding);
            }
            payrollReportView.SumGrossEarnings = grossTotal;
            payrollReportView.SumPeriod401K = gross401KTotal;
            payrollReportView.SumPeriod401KCatchUp = gross401KCatchUpTotal;
            payrollReportView.SumFederalWithholding = federalTotal;
            payrollReportView.SumSSNWithholding = SSNTotal;
            payrollReportView.SumMedicareWithholding = medicareTotal;
            payrollReportView.SumStateWithholding = stateTotal;
            payrollReportView.SumNetPay = netTotal;
            payrollReportView.SumTips = tipsTotal;
            payrollReportView.SumTips_Cash = tipsCashTotal;
            payrollReportView.SumFederalWithholding = extraFederalTotal;
            payrollReportView.SumStateExtraWithholding = extraStateTotal;
            var report = new ViewAsPdf("PayrollView",payrollReportView);
            return report;
            //return new RazorPageAsPdf(this);
        }
```

Razor View Code:

```
@model MvcPayroll.Models.PayrollReportView

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Payroll Register";
}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" />

<h1>Payroll Reports</h1>
    <p><button>@Html.ActionLink("Download as PDF","PrintPayroll", "PayrollReports",
                new
                {
                    SelectedCompanyID = @ViewBag.CompanyID,
                    endingWeekString = @ViewBag.endingWeekString,
                    endingDateString = @ViewBag.endingDateString,
                    SelectedEmployeeID = @ViewBag.SelectedEmployeeId
                })</button></p>

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Company Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Employee Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    SSN
                </th>
                <th>
                    Weekending Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    Gross Earnings
                </th>
                <th>
                    401K
                </th>
                <th>
                    401K Catchup
                </th>
                <th>
                    Federal Withholding
                </th>
                <th>
                    Fed Extra Withholding
                </th>
                <th>
                    SSN Withholding
                </th>
                <th>
                    Medicare Withholding
                </th>
                <th>
                    State Withholding
                </th>
                <th>
                    State Extra Withholding
                </th>
                <th>
                    Net Pay
                </th>
                <th>
                    Tips
                </th>
                <th>
                    Tips - Cash
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @{ decimal subtotalGrossEarnings = 0;
                decimal subtotalPeriod401K = 0;
                decimal subtotalPeriod401KCatchUp = 0;
                decimal subtotalFederalWithholding = 0;
                decimal subtotalSSNWithholding = 0;
                decimal subtotalMedicareWithholding = 0;
                decimal subtotalStateWithholding = 0;
                decimal subtotalNetPay = 0;
                decimal? subtotalTips = 0;
                decimal? subtotalTips_Cash = 0;
                decimal? subtotalFedExtraWithholding = 0;
                decimal? subtotalStateExtraWithholding = 0;
                string oldEmployeeName;
                if (Model != null && Model.PayrollDetails.Count() > 0)
                    oldEmployeeName = Model.PayrollDetails[0].EmployeeName;
                else
                    oldEmployeeName = string.Empty;

                @foreach (PayrollReport item in Model.PayrollDetails)
                {
                    // See if employee changed. If it did spit out the Subtotal
                    @if ((oldEmployeeName != item.EmployeeName) && (Model.endingDate != null))
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Sub Total:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @String.Format("{0:0.00}", subtotalGrossEarnings)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @String.Format("{0:0.00}", subtotalPeriod401K)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @String.Format("{0:0.00}", subtotalPeriod401KCatchUp)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @String.Format("{0:0.00}", subtotalFederalWithholding)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @String.Format("{0:0.00}", subtotalFedExtraWithholding)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @String.Format("{0:0.00}", subtotalSSNWithholding)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @String.Format("{0:0.00}", subtotalMedicareWithholding)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @String.Format("{0:0.00}", subtotalStateWithholding)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @String.Format("{0:0.00}", subtotalStateExtraWithholding)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @String.Format("{0:0.00}", subtotalNetPay)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @String.Format("{0:0.00}", subtotalTips)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @String.Format("{0:0.00}", subtotalTips_Cash)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        oldEmployeeName = item.EmployeeName;
                        subtotalGrossEarnings = item.GrossEarnings;
                        subtotalPeriod401K = item.Period401K;
                        subtotalPeriod401KCatchUp = item.Period401KCatchUp;
                        subtotalFederalWithholding = item.FederalWithholding;
                        subtotalSSNWithholding = item.SSNWithholding;
                        subtotalMedicareWithholding = item.MedicareWithholding;
                        subtotalStateWithholding = item.StateWithholding;
                        subtotalNetPay = item.NetPay;
                        subtotalTips = item.Tips;
                        subtotalTips_Cash = item.Tips_Cash;
                        subtotalFedExtraWithholding = item.FedExtraWithholding;
                        subtotalStateExtraWithholding = item.StateExtraWithholding;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        subtotalGrossEarnings = subtotalGrossEarnings + item.GrossEarnings;
                        subtotalPeriod401K = subtotalPeriod401K + item.Period401K;
                        subtotalPeriod401KCatchUp = subtotalPeriod401KCatchUp + item.Period401KCatchUp;
                        subtotalFederalWithholding = subtotalFederalWithholding + item.FederalWithholding;
                        subtotalSSNWithholding = subtotalSSNWithholding + item.SSNWithholding;
                        subtotalMedicareWithholding = subtotalMedicareWithholding + item.MedicareWithholding;
                        subtotalStateWithholding = subtotalStateWithholding + item.StateWithholding;
                        subtotalNetPay = subtotalNetPay + item.NetPay;
                        subtotalTips = subtotalTips + item.Tips;
                        subtotalTips_Cash = subtotalTips_Cash + item.Tips_Cash;
                        oldEmployeeName = item.EmployeeName;
                        subtotalFedExtraWithholding = subtotalFedExtraWithholding + item.FedExtraWithholding;
                        subtotalStateExtraWithholding = subtotalStateExtraWithholding + item.StateExtraWithholding;
                    }

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CompanyName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SSN)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WeekEndingDate)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GrossEarnings)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Period401K)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Period401KCatchUp)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FederalWithholding)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FedExtraWithholding)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SSNWithholding)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MedicareWithholding)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StateWithholding)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StateExtraWithholding)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NetPay)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tips)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tips_Cash)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
            @if (Model.endingDate != null)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Sub Total:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @String.Format("{0:0.00}", subtotalGrossEarnings)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @String.Format("{0:0.00}", subtotalPeriod401K)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @String.Format("{0:0.00}", subtotalPeriod401KCatchUp)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @String.Format("{0:0.00}", subtotalFederalWithholding)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @String.Format("{0:0.00}", subtotalFedExtraWithholding)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @String.Format("{0:0.00}", subtotalSSNWithholding)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @String.Format("{0:0.00}", subtotalMedicareWithholding)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @String.Format("{0:0.00}", subtotalStateWithholding)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @String.Format("{0:0.00}", subtotalStateExtraWithholding)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @String.Format("{0:0.00}", @subtotalNetPay)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @String.Format("{0:0.00}", subtotalTips)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @String.Format("{0:0.00}", subtotalTips_Cash)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            @if (Model.endingDate != null)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Totals
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.SumGrossEarnings)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.SumPeriod401K)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.SumPeriod401KCatchUp)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.SumFederalWithholding)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.SumFedExtraWithholding)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.SumSSNWithholding)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.SumMedicareWithholding)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.SumStateWithholding)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.SumStateExtraWithholding)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.SumNetPay)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.SumTips)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.SumTips_Cash)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Comment: I'm a little confused about your problem. Does it not render correctly as PDF file in Bravo? or Edge? And I found a [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59349176/razor-pages-pdf-generation-with-rotativa-model-null), this may be help you.

Comment: It does not render correctly in neither Bravo nor Edge. I tried the link you sent me but I am having some issues. The class being extended is PageModel, but my class is a controller. Also, there is an override for CallTheDriver, but it doesn't let me override this class. Am I using the wrong version of Rotativa? Also, the link says Rotativa doesn't work with Razor, but in some of the other posts I have found Razor seems to work fine.

Comment: Hi, @David. I use Rotativa to generate PDFs always based on Razor views, and it works fine, as you stated before. Receiving a pure JSON as a result might be related to some trouble in your client code, could you share your Razor view code and the javaascript/AJAX you are using to call the controller actions, please? And just to clarify, I assume you are trying to make you app work both on Brave and Edge and this works fine on Edge and fails in Brave?

Comment: I created a simple example and tested it in Edge Version 96.0.1054.53 (Official build), it worked well as Dave Miler mentioned. Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfV0y.png). Can you check the `content-type` attribute in Response Header, it should be `application/pdf`.

Comment: Xudong thanks for your help. Your post caused me to dig in deeper and find out the solution to my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xudong, you were right about the response header being wrong. I downloaded a .net project which worked. I then did some more online searches and realized that I was using .net Core so I needed to download the .net Core version of Rotativa not the .net 4.6 version. With some help from the link, [PDFCore](https://developpaper.com/how-to-use-rotativa-to-create-pdf-details-in-asp-net-core-mvc/) , I was able to get my program to generate PDFs.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Glad to hear it's working now! As Xudong Peng recommends, please, remember to mark this as an answer.

Comment: @David It would be most helpful if you also added your solution and insights to your answer please